# Is there a good editor on the Mac supports the new Razor View Engine format from ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to make it easier for the designers working on the Macs at the office to work with a new ASP.NET MVC 3 site using the new Razor View Engine template format.

Are there any editors which would help a user on a Mac edit the new .cshtml format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version on Mono Develop included support for MVC 3 and Razor. See release note [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10). Your designers should be able to open cshtml using that.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your designers should be just producing HTML/CSS (using the editor of their choice), then it's up to the developers to convert their designs into code (including C# & Razor)?

If (as Simon G suggests) you can get your entire ASP.NET MVC 3 solution, built in Visual Studio in Windows, to work in Mono on a Mac, then great, but I would foresee some compatibility/cross-platform issues in doing so, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine use Visual Studio in a virtual machine. Using VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

Parallels and Visual Studio works great for me.